# How can I hide a sub-report that has no records

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a sub report on another report that could have no records in it. Is there a way I can hide the report (and its label) when there are no records to display?

Alternately, is there a way to return a single row (e.g., "None") when an SQL re-query returns no rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a HasData property:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Me.MySubreport.Visible = Me.MySubreport.Report.HasData
End Sub
```